# Why does systemctl start docker with different arguments

Tags: linux, vmware, docker

I'm running an instance of VMware's Photon distro, which uses systemctl.  I want docker to use a TCP port so I can play with the REST API.  I used 'systemctl stop docker' and the service stops.

I then changed `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user-wants/docker.service` to say

```
ExecStart=/bin/docker -H :4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -d -s overlay
```

If I run that exact command line by hand, everything works; '`docker version`' and '`docker -H :4243 version`' return identical results.

When I start the service, however, only the first command works.  '`ps -ef`' doesn't show the two -H options, and journalctl doesn't show the process listening on the TCP port.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: After changing the service file did you run `systemctl daemon-reload` to make sure systemd reread the changed file?

Comment: Nope.  I've always been an init.d guy, and I'm learning a lot today.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to re-enable the service in order for the changes to take effect ?

```
systemctl reenable docker.service
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because you were fast and helped me find the actual problem.  Your answer led me to try 'systemctl --help', which led me to 'systemctl show docker', which told me I was changing the wrong file.  Turns out I was modifying /etc/systemd/system/docker.service, but that's supposed to be a symlink to /lib/systemd/system/docker.service, which wasn't getting changed.  I blame the lack of vim on the Photon image, forcing me to use, hmmm, exotic tools to edit the file, which broke the link.